# iOS app crashes "tcpConnWorkQueue"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, afnetworking, crashlytics

Is anyone else facing this issue?

```
Thread : Crashed: tcpConnWorkQueue
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x000000019344f270 __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001934ed228 pthread_kill + 112
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x00000001933c6b18 abort + 112
3  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x000000019348a3e4 _nano_malloc_check_clear
4  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x00000001934892f8 nano_free + 192
5  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001825c9a04 CFRelease + 1064
6  CFNetwork                      0x000000018203f5dc SocketStream::~SocketStream() + 472
7  CFNetwork                      0x000000018203f3ec SocketStream::~SocketStream() + 28
8  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001825c9724 CFRelease + 328
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x000000019330d49c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x000000019330d45c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000193317554 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1216
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000193310564 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 132
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000193319224 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 656
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x000000019331a75c _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 108
15 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001934e92e4 _pthread_wqthread + 816
```

//Main thread

```
Thread : com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x000000019872ce7c mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x000000019872ccf8 mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000187941808 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 200
3  CoreFoundation                 0x000000018793f75c __CFRunLoopRun + 940
4  CoreFoundation                 0x000000018786d664 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
5  UIFoundation                   0x0000000194817500 -[NSHTMLReader _loadUsingWebKit] + 1988
6  UIFoundation                   0x00000001948188c0 -[NSHTMLReader attributedString] + 32
7  UIFoundation                   0x00000001947b65e4 _NSReadAttributedStringFromURLOrData + 5804
8  UIFoundation                   0x00000001947b4e80 -[NSAttributedString(NSAttributedStringUIFoundationAdditions) initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error:] + 148
9  The App                   0x00000001000b27b0 -[LAItem setItemDescriptionHtml:] (LAItem.m:108)
10 The Test App                   0x00000001000b1e80 -[LAItem initWithDataDictionary:] (LAItem.m:46)
11 The Test App                   0x00000001000b25dc +[LAItem itemsWithDataArray:] (LAItem.m:93)
12 The Test App                   0x00000001001394f4 -[LATest updateWithDataDictionary:] (LATest.m:234)
13 The Test App                   0x000000010015fab8 __47-[DetailViewController getTestDetailFeed]_block_invoke (TestDetailViewController.m:165)
14 The Test App                   0x00000001001843dc __86-[DataCenter sendGetRequestWithUrlEndPoint:urlParameters:successBlock:failureBlock:]_block_invoke (LADataCenter.m:163)
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x000000019860549c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x000000019860545c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000198609a70 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 932
18 CoreFoundation                 0x00000001879418dc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
19 CoreFoundation                 0x000000018793f984 __CFRunLoopRun + 1492
20 CoreFoundation                 0x000000018786d664 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
21 GraphicsServices               0x00000001909a75a4 GSEventRunModal + 168
22 UIKit                          0x000000018c172984 UIApplicationMain + 1488
23 The Test App                   0x00000001001375d0 main (main.m:16)
24 libdyld.dylib                  0x000000019862ea08 start + 4
```

I am using `AFNetworking` kit for API hit.I can't find the exact scenario.  it crashes very often.
I got the trace from Crashlytics framework.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.